# Prefix Meaning "At Most"?

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics, prefixes

Is there a prefix meaning "at most" or "capped at"? I'd like to describe a spherical cap ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap), [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html)) that is at most a hemisphere. The blue solid in the diagram below shows the type of cap I'm comfortable referring to as a *subhemispherical cap* (a term I just made up to differentiate from the red solid, which is also a spherical cap,) however 'sub-' is strictly less than, whereas I mean to say less than or equal to. I thought of *subhemispherical cap or hemisphere*, which depicts nicely that a hemispherical cap is in fact a hemisphere, but it does sound somewhat cleaner to call it a *subhemi- or hemispherical cap* (although the oddity of calling a hemisphere a hemispherical cap makes me prefer the former.) I list hemi- second both times as it is the edge case.

Still, what I really want is to combine the two into one term, i.e. *[prefix]hemispherical cap*. This would avoid the awkwardness of those phrasings and would be an easily repeatable phrase in a paper.

By the way I do find unfortunate that the word *cap* here does not fit with the common English usage, synonymous with *lid*, if it did I could just call it a spherical cap.

Also this has to be easy to understand, if the prefix is too niche I can't use it (although I'd still be curious to hear it.)

[image: Spherical Cap]

EDITED: For extra clarity on what I want, what I came up with, and added an image.

Comment: The word *maximally* could suit your need -- a maximally hemispherical cap.

Comment: Thanks @YosefBaskin, I kinda like it! +1 for being a mathematical adjective. Although it does seem very slightly awkward, as in it's not entirely clear from your usage that 'maximally' refers directly to 'hemi-'. (This is mostly why I was hoping for a prefix.) It's the best I've got for now though.

Comment: It's up to you. The adverb modifies hemispherical directly. It means an at-most-half-globe of a cap.

Comment: This doesn't work. If something is "maximally X", that means it is as X as it could possibly be, not that it varies with a maximum of X.

Comment: True, that's something else I couldn't put my finger on. Especially mathematically that would be implying that it is as hemispherical as possible (a useless thing to say.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say that the cap is within or inside of the hemispherical cap: Endohemispherical cap

End- meaning inside of or within, as in
endorse, endocardial, endergonic, endoskeleton, endoscope, endogenous

Source: https://www.quia.com/files/quia/users/skrichard/ComSkills2/RootsPrefixesSuffixes

Comment: Thanks, seems the best! Doesn't have the implications of sub- and is common enough to be understood.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the language of [**topology**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_(topology)) would give you more scope than the language of spherical geometry, e.g.

- The surface of the sphere is a **set of points**  *S*
- A **partial cover** of *S*  a collection of subsets that contains
  some but not all of the points in *S*.
- A **bounded partial cover** is a collection that satisfies some
  bound, e.g. on the shape, size, number of subsets, or any other
  property one might care to define.
- A **hemispherically bounded partial cover** would then have the
  properties you are looking for, provided that you define
  "hemispherically bounded" in an earlier step.

This is not a single-word answer, but with such a definition you could then introduce a term of your own, such as a **cup cover**, and use it within the scope of your document.

I have to confess that this is a somewhat frivolous use of topological language, but it might do the job.

Comment: Thanks, a helpful view and rigorous! I think too much explanation is required though for my purposes :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Mathematically, you want to say *where theta is <= 90 degrees*.

By [definition](http://mathinsight.org/definition/proper_subset), a subset can also contain the entire set.  By analogy, a sub-hemispherical cap can include the entire hemisphere.  I would state this as a definition before using it.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if you understood what a spherical cap is, I added an image to clarify. Both the blue and red sections above are spherical caps; however, I want to include in my definition those that are like the blue, also include those that are half a sphere, and exclude those that are like the red. Including the half a sphere in the description is of mathematical importance.  I did also already see that Q&A, while you could refer to the red section as a superhemispherical cap that is not what I was looking for. They do not seem to discuss an alternative to 'sub-' that includes the object.

Comment: I understood what a spherical cap was. But I did misunderstand that you were asking for a range of subsets.  I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 Good point about subsets, but regarding *sub-* as a prefix, I'm not sure I agree, *sub-* usually means below or under.  As far as I can tell, "subset" is the only use of the prefix where it can include the complete entity as well.  It seems to me that prefixing a word with *sub-* probably would imply *anything under that level*.  That's my take at least.

Comment: Thanks @MikeJRamsey56 and RaceYouAnytime. It is a great point that that works at the least with 'subset', so given a definition before usage I could see that as being a proper term. I do agree though that generally it seems unintuitive and bears the connotation of a strict inequality. ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sub-)) Then again, 'cap' also used strangely, so it might be fair. :) In other words I'm not extremely enthused but I could see it working. Minus a prefix that means what I want, this could be the way to go.